# Can a component be found using its key?

Tags: vue.js, testing, vue-test-utils

Does `Vue test-utils` support looking for components in a list using their key? If not is there other ways of looking for components that are generated in the form of a list in vue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't query a component using the key in the `findComponent()` method.

But you can fetch all components within your list, and then filter them like a regular array.
Just provide the right condition to find the item you want (usings its props, attrs or whatever)

```js
const items = wrapper.findAllComponents(MyListItem)
const foundItem = items.wrappers.find(listItem => list.props('id') === 'theIdILookFor')
```

Comment: Does it work the same for `key` and `id`?

Comment: No, you can't access the `key` value in any way. It's a reserved attribute only accessible by the Virtual Dom, AFAIK it's not exposed anywhere in the component.